# How to define time-dependent, discrete parameter?

Tags: python-3.x, differential-equations, gekko

Recently, I have built a small model with GEKKO. It contains a Parameter which actually changes with time. How can I implement that? I tried using `if3`, but it gives an error.

Here's the MWE:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Started on 10-08-2019

@author: winkmal
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO
#Initialize Model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

# Parameters
k_1     = m.Param(value = 0.19)
f_1     = m.Param(value = 29.0)
V_liq   = m.Param(value = 159.0)

q_in    = m.Param(value = 2.5)
X_in    = m.Param(value = 271.77)
Y_in    = m.Param(value = 164.34)

X       = m.Var(value = 11.55)
Y       = m.Var(value = 11.55*0.2)
rho_1   = m.Intermediate(k_1*X)
q_prod  = m.Intermediate(0.52*f_1*X)

m.time  = np.arange(0,5,1/12)

m.Equations([X.dt() == q_in/V_liq*(X_in - X) - rho_1, \
             Y.dt() == q_in/V_liq*(Y_in - Y)]) 
#Dynamic simulation
m.options.IMODE = 4
m.solve(disp=False)

plt.plot(m.time, X.value)
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('X')
plt.show()
```

I tried the following:

```
q_in    = m.if3(m.time - 2, 0, 2.5)
```

so that `q_in` would be 0 initially, and become 2.5 at `time = 2`.
But I get the following error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gekko/gekko.py", line 1838, in solve
    raise Exception(apm_error)

Exception:  @error: Equation Definition
 Equation without an equality (=) or inequality (>,<)
 (((1-int_v5))*([-2.-1.91666667-1.83333333-1.75-1.66666667-1.58333333
 STOPPING...
```

Do you have an idea how I can achieve this? Actually, this variable jumps several times between 0 and 60, and I have the time points available in a CSV file. Ideally, I could create a loop that would check at every iteration if it's time for `q_in` to change, and overwrite the current value accordingly.

Comment: Can you find where exactly the error is raised? From the documentation I get the impression that `if3` is mis-applied here, as `t` is not a static parameter of the model. It would be slightly better to use `q_in = lambda t: 0 if t<2 else 2.5` and even better if you could split the integration interval, so that the IC of the second segment are the last values from the first.

Comment: By https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/imode.html#dynamics the ODE solver expects not only a continuous, but a smooth right side in ODE. You are really using the package outside of specifications. What could work is using several instances of the ODE à la https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#optimization-of-multiple-linked-phases where the first instance has `q_in=0` and the second has `q_in=2.5` and the state of the second instance is linked via `m.Connection` to the first at the time index for time `t=2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the input from a CSV and assign the time-varying values to `q_in.value` either during Parameter initialization (see Example #1) or else in a loop where the value changes each time integration interval (see Example #2). Examples 1 and 2 both produce the following result but Example 1 is faster.

[image: Integration result]

Example 1 may also be faster with option `m.options.IMODE=7` if you have a very long time horizon. `IMODE=7` uses a sequential solution method instead of a simultaneous solution method.

**Example 1**

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO
t = np.arange(0,5,1/12)
step = [0 if z<2 else 2.5 for z in t]
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
k_1     = m.Param(value = 0.19)
f_1     = m.Param(value = 29.0)
V_liq   = m.Param(value = 159.0)
q_in    = m.Param(value = step)
X_in    = m.Param(value = 271.77)
Y_in    = m.Param(value = 164.34)
X       = m.Var(value = 11.55)
Y       = m.Var(value = 11.55*0.2)
rho_1   = m.Intermediate(k_1*X)
q_prod  = m.Intermediate(0.52*f_1*X)
m.time  = t
m.Equations([X.dt() == q_in/V_liq*(X_in - X) - rho_1, \
             Y.dt() == q_in/V_liq*(Y_in - Y)]) 
m.options.IMODE = 4
m.solve(disp=False)
plt.plot(m.time,q_in.value,label=r'$q_{in}$')
plt.plot(m.time, X.value,label='X')
plt.plot(m.time, Y.value,label='Y')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.show()
```

**Example 2**

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO
t = np.arange(0,5,1/12)
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
k_1     = m.Param(value = 0.19)
f_1     = m.Param(value = 29.0)
V_liq   = m.Param(value = 159.0)
q_in    = m.Param()
X_in    = m.Param(value = 271.77)
Y_in    = m.Param(value = 164.34)
X       = m.Var(value = 11.55)
Y       = m.Var(value = 11.55*0.2)
rho_1   = m.Intermediate(k_1*X)
q_prod  = m.Intermediate(0.52*f_1*X)
m.time  = [t[0],t[1]]
m.Equations([X.dt() == q_in/V_liq*(X_in - X) - rho_1, \
             Y.dt() == q_in/V_liq*(Y_in - Y)]) 
m.options.IMODE = 4
# store Xs and Ys for plotting
for i in range (1,len(t)):
    q_in.value = 0 if t[i]<2 else 2.5
    m.solve(disp=False)
    if i==1:
        Xs = [X.value[0]]
        Ys = [Y.value[0]]
    Xs.append(X.value[1])
    Ys.append(Y.value[1])
step = [0 if z<2 else 2.5 for z in t]
plt.plot(t,step,label=r'$q_{in}$')
plt.plot(t, Xs,label='X')
plt.plot(t, Ys,label='Y')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.show()
```

If you need to make `q_in` dependent on the value of some of your variables then you can use the `m.if3` function. However, this is a more challenging problem to solve because the `m.if3` function converts the problem into a Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming form that may take longer to solve. Here is an example where `q_in=0`when `X>8` and `q_in=2.5` when `X<=8`. However, it didn't converge for me. I'm not sure why and I'd need to do some additional digging but I though you'd like to have it in case it works for you.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
k_1     = m.Param(value = 0.19)
f_1     = m.Param(value = 29.0)
V_liq   = m.Param(value = 159.0)
X_in    = m.Param(value = 271.77)
Y_in    = m.Param(value = 164.34)
X       = m.Var(value = 11.55,name='X')
Y       = m.Var(value = 11.55*0.2,name='Y')
rho_1   = m.Intermediate(k_1*X)
q_prod  = m.Intermediate(0.52*f_1*X)
q_in    = m.if3(8-X, 0.0, 2.5)
m.time  = np.arange(0,5,1/12)
m.Equations([X.dt() == q_in/V_liq*(X_in - X) - rho_1, \
             Y.dt() == q_in/V_liq*(Y_in - Y)]) 
m.options.IMODE = 6
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve(disp=True)
plt.plot(m.time,q_in.value,label=r'$q_{in}$')
plt.plot(m.time, X.value,label='X')
plt.plot(m.time, Y.value,label='Y')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.show()
```

There are also a [few other examples here](https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/PythonDifferentialEquations) on solving ODEs with time-varying inputs with Gekko.

Comment: Actually, I could get `if3` to work with the following small changes to my code:
`m.time  = np.arange(0,5,1/12);
t       = m.Param(value = m.time);`
...
`q_in    = m.Var();
q_in    = m.if3(t - 2, 0, 2.5);`

Comment: Before editing the OP too much, I will mark this as Solved (*one* jump during `t` is possible) and post a new question which deals with several jumps, since I could not yet get this to work.