# How to implement rectangular pulses (discontinuities) on ODE right-hand side?

Tags: python-3.x, differential-equations, gekko

In addition to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57443890/how-to-define-time-dependent-discrete-parameter), I would like to have several jumps during simulation time.
As @LutzL proposed, I tried to perform one simulation per phase in a loop, and use the `Connection` method to stitch them together, with the final states of `Phase 1 == initial states of Phase 2` etc. But I get an error, saying

> Exception:  @error: Model Expression  *** Error in syntax of function
>   string: Missing operator
>
> Position: 6
>    11.55,11.55,11.55,11.55,11.55
>       ?

The feeding times and rates are to be understood as: `[t_start, t_end]`, so there is two feeding events (starting at `t = 2` and `t = 3.1`, respectively). one takes 0.7 and the other 0.2 (days). So there is five phases (`numOfPhases`): Before first feeding, first feeding, between first and second feeding, second feeding, after second feeding.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO
# Construct input schedule
feedingTimes = np.array([2, 2.7, 3.1, 3.3])
feedingRates = np.array([60, 0, 430, 0])
tf      = 5
# Number of phases
numOfPhases = len(feedingTimes) + 1
# Construct time vectors (unequally spaced for now)
timeVector = np.zeros((numOfPhases, 10))
timeVector[0,:] = np.linspace(0, feedingTimes[0], 10)
for tI in np.arange(1,numOfPhases-1):
    timeVector[tI,:] = np.linspace(feedingTimes[tI-1], feedingTimes[tI], 10)
timeVector[-1,:] = np.linspace(feedingTimes[-1], tf, 10) 

#Initialize Model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

q_in    = [m.Var(0.0, lb=-2, ub=500, fixed_initial=False) for i in range(numOfPhases)]

# (Example of) same parameter for each phase
k_1     = m.Param(value = 0.19)
f_1     = m.Param(value = 29.0)
V_liq   = m.Param(value = 159.0)

X_in    = m.Param(value = 271.77)
Y_in    = m.Param(value = 164.34)
# Variables (one version of x for each phase)
X       = [m.Var(value = 11.55) for i in range(numOfPhases)]
Y       = [m.Var(value = 11.55*0.2) for i in range(numOfPhases)]

rho_1   = [m.Intermediate(k_1*X) for i in range(numOfPhases)]
q_prod  = [m.Intermediate(0.52*f_1*X) for i in range(numOfPhases)]

# Equations (different for each phase)
for pI in range(numOfPhases):
    m.time = timeVector[pI,:]
    m.Equations([X[pI].dt() == q_in[pI]/V_liq*(X_in - X[pI]) - rho_1[pI], \
                 Y[pI].dt() == q_in[pI]/V_liq*(Y_in - Y[pI])])

# Connect phases together at endpoints
for pI in range(numOfPhases-1):
    m.Connection(X[pI+1], X[pI], 1, len(m.time)-1, 1, 3)
    m.Connection(Y[pI+1], Y[pI], 1, len(m.time)-1, 1, 3)

m.options.IMODE = 4
m.solve(disp=False)

plt.plot(m.time, q_in.value, label='q_in')
plt.plot(m.time, X.value, label='X')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('X')
plt.grid()
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Intermediates `rho_1` and `q_prod` are not defined correctly because `X` is a variable list, not a single variable.

```py
rho_1   = [m.Intermediate(k_1*X[i]) for i in range(numOfPhases)]
q_prod  = [m.Intermediate(0.52*f_1*X[i]) for i in range(numOfPhases)]
```

However, I don't think you need an array of `X` values for your problem because you want the final condition of one segment to equal the initial condition of the next segment and your equations do not change from one segment to the next. Multiple definitions of `m.time` are not allowed. You only define time once for each solve and each segment must have the same time. There is a way to time scale each segment so that it is variable but this is a more advanced topic. Also, the `timeVector` must not have two sequential values that are equal (must be increasing). I added 1e-5 to the start of each feeding phase.

```py
timeVector = np.zeros((numOfPhases, 10))
timeVector[0,:] = np.linspace(0, feedingTimes[0], 10)
for tI in np.arange(1,numOfPhases-1):
    timeVector[tI,:] = np.linspace(feedingTimes[tI-1]+1e-5, feedingTimes[tI], 10)
timeVector[-1,:] = np.linspace(feedingTimes[-1]+1e-5, tf, 10)
```

The `timeVector` is a `(5,10)` numpy array. You need to flatten it into a 1D array for Gekko. I made this modification with the `numpy.reshape` function.

```py
m.time = np.reshape(timeVector, -1)
```

If you need different equations for different time segments then you may need to define an array of `X` values with different equations. Because you use the same equations for each segment, I recommend a sequential approach instead as shown below.

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO
# Construct input schedule
feedingTimes = np.array([2, 2.7, 3.1, 3.3])
feedingRates = np.array([60, 0, 430, 0])
tf      = 5
# Number of phases
numOfPhases = len(feedingTimes) + 1
# Construct time vectors (unequally spaced for now)
timeVector = np.zeros((numOfPhases, 10))
timeVector[0,:] = np.linspace(0, feedingTimes[0], 10)
for tI in np.arange(1,numOfPhases-1):
    timeVector[tI,:] = np.linspace(feedingTimes[tI-1]+1e-5, feedingTimes[tI], 10)
timeVector[-1,:] = np.linspace(feedingTimes[-1]+1e-5, tf, 10)

feedVector = np.zeros(tf*10)
for i in range(len(feedingRates)):
    feedVector[(i+1)*10:(i+2)*10] = feedingRates[i]

#Initialize Model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = np.reshape(timeVector, -1)

q_in    = m.Param(value=feedVector)

# (Example of) same parameter for each phase
k_1     = m.Param(value = 0.19)
f_1     = m.Param(value = 29.0)
V_liq   = m.Param(value = 159.0)

X_in    = m.Param(value = 271.77)
Y_in    = m.Param(value = 164.34)
# Variables (one version of x for each phase)
X       = m.Var(value = 11.55)
Y       = m.Var(value = 11.55*0.2)

rho_1   = m.Intermediate(k_1*X)
q_prod  = m.Intermediate(0.52*f_1*X)

# Equations (different for each phase)
m.Equations([X.dt() == q_in/V_liq*(X_in - X) - rho_1, \
             Y.dt() == q_in/V_liq*(Y_in - Y)])

m.options.IMODE = 4
m.solve(disp=True)

plt.plot(m.time, q_in.value, label='q_in')
plt.plot(m.time, X.value, label='X')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.grid()
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

If you need to eventually switch to optimization / control and want only one value of feedrate for each segment then I recommend the parameter `MV_STEP_HOR` as [described in the documentation](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionApmMvStepHor).

Comment: Thanks. Would it be possible to restrict the elements in `timeVector` to *only* those which are either an element of `(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` or `feedingTimes`?
Does APMonitor actually *solve* the equation system at all timesteps in `m.time`, or does it use internal heuristics and interpolation like Matlab's ode solvers?
Eventually, I will need to switch to optimization, but First things first.

Comment: You probably need to add additional points to avoid integration error. Gekko / APMonitor use orthogonal collocation on finite elements: https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/OrthogonalCollocation  Gekko also allows optimization.